# ActionEvent in JavaFX

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, actionevent

This program draws up a graph using Canvas. I'm currently working on the "samplet" button. The idea is to make the program draw up a graph based on the arrays in the "sampletTidsserie" method. When I click the button, nothing really happens! What is wrong?

I'm just adding the main program here.

```
package application;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import tidsserier.Tidsserie;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Main extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {


        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,950,550);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Graftegner");
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1000, 450);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        tegnGraf(gc);

        // Lager labels (x-akse):
        Label label1 = new Label("-2");
        Label label2 = new Label("-1");
        Label label3 = new Label("0");
        Label label4 = new Label("1");
        Label label5 = new Label("2");
        Label label6 = new Label("3");
        Label label7 = new Label("4");
        Label label8 = new Label("5");

     // Lager labels (y-akse):
        Label label9 = new Label("10");
        Label label10 = new Label("20");
        Label label11 = new Label("30");
        Label label12 = new Label("40");
        Label label13 = new Label("50");
        Label label14 = new Label("60");
        Label label15 = new Label("70");
        Label label16 = new Label("80");
        Label label17 = new Label("90");
        Label label18 = new Label("100");
        Label label19 = new Label("110");
        Label label20 = new Label("120");
        Label label21 = new Label("130");
        Label label22 = new Label("140");
        Label label23 = new Label("150");

        // Plassering av labels x-akse:
        label1.setLayoutX(63);
        label2.setLayoutX(63);
        label3.setLayoutX(70);
        label4.setLayoutX(70);
        label5.setLayoutX(70);
        label6.setLayoutX(70);
        label7.setLayoutX(70);
        label8.setLayoutX(70);
        label1.setLayoutY(390);
        label2.setLayoutY(340);
        label3.setLayoutY(290);
        label4.setLayoutY(240);
        label5.setLayoutY(190);
        label6.setLayoutY(140);
        label7.setLayoutY(90);
        label8.setLayoutY(40);

        // Plassering av labels y-akse(x-koordinater):
        label9.setLayoutX(140);
        label10.setLayoutX(190);
        label11.setLayoutX(240);
        label12.setLayoutX(290);
        label13.setLayoutX(340);
        label14.setLayoutX(390);
        label15.setLayoutX(440);
        label16.setLayoutX(490);
        label17.setLayoutX(540);
        label18.setLayoutX(590);
        label19.setLayoutX(640);
        label20.setLayoutX(690);
        label21.setLayoutX(740);
        label22.setLayoutX(790);
        label23.setLayoutX(840);

        // Y-koordinater (alle er 310):
        label9.setLayoutY(310);label10.setLayoutY(310); label11.setLayoutY(310);label12.setLayoutY(310);
        label13.setLayoutY(310);label14.setLayoutY(310);label15.setLayoutY(310);label16.setLayoutY(310);
        label17.setLayoutY(310);label18.setLayoutY(310);label19.setLayoutY(310); label20.setLayoutY(310);
        label21.setLayoutY(310);label22.setLayoutY(310);label23.setLayoutY(310);

        // Lager knapper:
        Button manuelt = new Button("Legg inn tidsserie manuelt");
        Button samplet = new Button("Legg inn samplet tidsserie");
        Button lagre = new Button("Lagre");
        Button lesinn = new Button("Les inn");

        // Plassering av knapper:
        manuelt.setLayoutY(500);
        samplet.setLayoutY(500);
        lagre.setLayoutY(500);
        lesinn.setLayoutY(500);
        manuelt.setLayoutX(50);
        samplet.setLayoutX(240);
        lagre.setLayoutX(428);
        lesinn.setLayoutX(487);

        // Knytter knappene opp mot event:
        manuelt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        samplet.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                sampletTidsserie();
                }
        });  
        lagre.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        lesinn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(canvas,manuelt,samplet,lagre,lesinn);
        root.getChildren().addAll(label1,label2,label3,label4,label5,label6,label7,label8,label9,label10,label11,label12,label13,label14,label15,label16,label17,label18,label19,label20,label21,label22,label23);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 private Tidsserie sampletTidsserie(){


     return null;

 }

 private void tegnGraf(GraphicsContext gc) {

        //Selve grafen:
        gc.strokeLine(100, 5, 100, 450);
        gc.strokeLine(100, 300, 900, 300);
        gc.strokeLine(95, 10, 100, 5);
        gc.strokeLine(100, 5, 105, 10);
        gc.strokeLine(895, 295, 900, 300);
        gc.strokeLine(895, 305, 900, 300);

        //Punkt y-akse:
        gc.strokeLine(95, 50, 105, 50);
        gc.strokeLine(95, 100, 105, 100);
        gc.strokeLine(95, 150, 105, 150);
        gc.strokeLine(95, 200, 105, 200);
        gc.strokeLine(95, 250, 105, 250);
        gc.strokeLine(95, 300, 105, 300);
        gc.strokeLine(95, 350, 105, 350);
        gc.strokeLine(95, 400, 105, 400);

        //Punkt x-akse:
        gc.strokeLine(150, 295, 150, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(200, 295, 200, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(250, 295, 250, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(300, 295, 300, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(350, 295, 350, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(400, 295, 400, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(450, 295, 450, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(500, 295, 500, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(550, 295, 550, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(600, 295, 600, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(650, 295, 650, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(700, 295, 700, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(750, 295, 750, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(800, 295, 800, 305);
        gc.strokeLine(850, 295, 850, 305);

        gc.strokeOval(150,350,5,5);

    }

 public void sampletTiddsserie(GraphicsContext gc) {

     double[] Tid = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150};
     double[] Verdi = {4.8, 4.5, 4.1, 4.1, 3.9, 3.8, 3.8, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.1, 4.8};
     //Tidsserie Serie = new tidsserier.ArrayTidsserie(Tid, Verdi);

     for (int i = 1; i<Verdi.length; i++) { 
        double verdi = Array.getDouble(Verdi, i);
        double tid = Array.getDouble(Tid, i);
        double y = 300-(50*verdi);
        double x = (tid*5)+100;
        gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        gc.strokeOval(x, y, 5, 5);

        if (i == 1){ 
            gc.strokeLine(100, 300, x, y);
        } else { 
            double verdi2 = Array.getDouble(Verdi, i-1);
            double tid2 = Array.getDouble(Tid, i-1);
            double y2 = 300-(50*verdi2);
            double x2 = (tid2*5)+100;
            gc.strokeLine(x2, y2, x, y);
        }
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the `sampletTidsserie` in the `onAction` handler, which is just a method returning `null`. You ignore the returned value.

I guess you actually wanted to call

```
sampletTiddsserie(gc);
```

Note that using 2 identifiers that are that similar as the names for methods should be avoided, if possible; even more so if the return types differ...

Also a note on accessing the arrays using `Array.getDouble` here: ***Don't do it.***

There is no benefit in using a method call instead of simply accessing the array element. E.g. use:

```
double verdi = Verdi[i];
```

instead of

```
double verdi = Array.getDouble(Verdi, i);
```

Comment: Thank u @fabian! Saved me from more headaches :)